# Reverse start and end point of animation in CSS

Tags: html, css, svg, web

I need help, I use this animation for line and now I need to reverse start and end point. Now, where the draw start I need end and where now draw line end I need start, basically reverse start and end point of draw line in animation which I use.

```css
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="340px" height="333px" viewBox="0 0 340 333" enable-background="new 0 0 340 333" xml:space="preserve">

  <path class="path" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M66.039,133.545c0,0-21-57,18-67s49-4,65,8
    s30,41,53,27s66,4,58,32s-5,44,18,57s22,46,0,45s-54-40-68-16s-40,88-83,48s11-61-11-80s-79-7-70-41
    C46.039,146.545,53.039,128.545,66.039,133.545z"/>
```

Comment: Use ` animation: dash 5s linear reverse;` instead

Comment: But I need only change the start point with end point, this your solution do is draw line from end to start and disappear I need to draw it!

Answer (score 1):

reverse the `stroke-dashoffset` like this add a `from` and `to`

```
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: -1000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
```

```css
path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: -1000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="340px" height="333px" viewBox="0 0 340 333" enable-background="new 0 0 340 333" xml:space="preserve">

  <path class="path" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M66.039,133.545c0,0-21-57,18-67s49-4,65,8
    s30,41,53,27s66,4,58,32s-5,44,18,57s22,46,0,45s-54-40-68-16s-40,88-83,48s11-61-11-80s-79-7-70-41
    C46.039,146.545,53.039,128.545,66.039,133.545z"/>
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But it disappears, but I need to draw this way

Comment: @pulitr what disappears? Here in the code it's working fine right?

Comment: No, in your solution line disappears from start to end, but I need to draw

Comment: I need to draw it as I do, but on the other way.

Comment: @pulitr this solution works fine, nothing disappears

Comment: You don't understand, I need to draw line, but from my solution to another side.

Comment: @pulitr I am sorry! I didn't get what you mean `I need to draw line, but from my solution to another side` , Can you please explain, so that I can help you out

Thank you